# How can i insert more than one button in a button in android_layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am a new android developer. How can I insert a button in another button. I have a button Department in it I want to insert other buttons IT, accounts, sales and Transport. That is when button department is clicked by the user it will allow the user to view and select the department. Please assist

Answer (score 0):

You should create a Linear layout in the xml file and place and position your accounts,IT, other departments button into linear layout/Relative layout but initially set that parent linear/Relative layout visibility to invisible like -
Add the below property

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

and on the click listener of your button ,set its visibility to true dynamically like below -

```
linearlayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: thanks that works and how will i refer the buttons account, IT and sales be viewed in the button Department after being clicked by the users

Comment: You can directly get them using findViewById method and perform whichever operation with the buttons.

Comment: Button accounts = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);   and do your work .

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to insert a button to another .. What you need is clickable layout including textViews as labels.

Here is an example:

your layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/department_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:background="#FFaa"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="IT"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:background="#FFffffaa"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="Account"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:background="#FFffaaff"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:text="sales"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And in your activity:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.department_layout);
linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //your stuff here
    }
});
```

Result:

[image: layout]

If you want to reach these widgets (TextView), then use:

```
TextView tvIt=(TextView)linearLayout.getChildAt(0);
TextView tvAccount=(TextView)linearLayout.getChildAt(1);
TextView tvSAle=(TextView)linearLayout.getChildAt(2);
```

Alternatively you could add simple set of buttons and they all share same listener.

Comment: thanks. Is there a way to refer all the buttons under button department after being clicked

Comment: You can get them as children of layout or via their Ids ( should be added to each button then )

Comment: an example on that please

Comment: I've update the answer . but what is the use case ? I mean why do you want to access these widgets ?

Comment: To enable the users review and access their departments under the button department when clicked.